# Make Process Explorer tray icon backgrounds black again

Tags: process-explorer, user-interface

I just updated Process Explorer to version 15.  With the update, the tray icons seem to have turned from black to transparent.  Is there any way I can get them to be black again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible from 15.01 (according to [SysInternals blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2011/07/25/updates-process-explorer-v15-01-and-tcpview-v3-05.aspx)):

> Process Explorer v15.01: This update adds the ability to select a
>   custom graph background color, (...).

In "Options" menu there is "Configure Colors..."

[image: Menu Options in Process Explorer]

When you choose it then you could change background color:

[image: Change Background]

Works for me:

[image: Olala it's working]

Comment: Updated to 15.04, and it works for me now.  Thanks.